# Ember.js - multiple components on a page

Tags: ember.js

I'm trying to build an Ember app and I'm running into some difficulty.

I have an index route, which I want to render the following page:

```
+--------------------------+
|   Welcome, foo@bar.com   |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
|        New Posts         |
|        ---------         |
|          *foo            |
|          *bar            |
|          *baz            |
|                          |
+--------------------------+
```

So I have an `Account` model, and a `Post` model. (which don't have any related fields)

I'm having conceptual difficulty with the following:

Ember routes have a `model` method which returns the model for the route. But what if I want multiple models to be associated with my route? In this case I have `Account` and `Post`. How do I make them *both* available to my page?

One thing I've tried is using `setupController` and manually setting `account` and `posts` on the controller so they can be accessed by the template. But if I can do this, what's the point/significance of the `model` method!?

Why does Ember want to associate a route with only a single model?

Appreciate any advice,

Thanks,
Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> One thing I've tried is using setupController and manually setting account and posts on the controller so they can be accessed by the template.

What you are doing is correct, this is what the `setupController` hook is for.

> But if I can do this, what's the point/significance of the model method!? Why does Ember want to associate a route with only a single model?

In **RC3**, preventing the default behavior was impossible. In RC4, implementing the `setupController` hook prevents the default behavior from happening. This is a potentially breaking change for dev's migrating to newer versions.

Also note that if your route implements the `setupController` hook and you want to preserve the default behavior (the `model` from also being invoked) make sure you call `this._super()` from within the `setupController` hook. You can read more [here](http://emberjs.com/blog/2013/05/28/ember-1-0-rc4.html) in the announcing blog post.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Interestingly, `model()` is being invoked even when I implement `setupController`. But I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

Using `model` callback has some advantages:

1. It automatically generate model callback when you define router.
2. In template, when you use `link-to "someRoute" model`, then when you click that link and transition to another route, the route will use the model you pass in for it's model (without calling `model` callback to get data).

See http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_model

But the biggest advantage I think, is promise support.

A route uses `model` callback to get data it needs, then in `setupController`, it pass the data to the second argument.

Notice what I mean setupController gets data from `model` callback. If the `model` callback returns a promise, the route will wait until this promise is resolved, then get the data from promise. If the promise is processing, the `setupController` is not called, and the template is not rendered.

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    // The server response an array of posts like [{name: 'foo'}, {name: 'bar'}, {name: 'baz'}]
    return $.get('/api/posts.json');
  },

  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    console.log(model);  // it's array, not promise object
    controller.set('model', model);
  }
});
```

When you can use `setupController` to do the same thing, it's like this:

```
App.PostsRoute = Em.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    $.get('/api/posts.json').then(function(data) {
      controller.set('model', data);
    });
  }
});
```

BUT, `setupController` does not support promise, that means if you get data from the server in the `setupController`, Ember will render template before the data is prepared. In many case it's not what we want.

BUT, the `model` seems not a good place to get multiple data from server. You can do that using `Ember.RSVP.all` with multiple promises. but you also need to consider `link-to`. I'm not sure what is the best practice 
to get multiple data in a route and wait them all prepared before rendering template. If anyone has a good solution, Please tell me!

For your situation, I think you can use different route to do this. After all I think something like "Welcome, foo@example.com" is a top bar for all of the pages, right? Then you can put it in `ApplicationRoute`, and render account info in `application.hbs` template.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Knowing about Ember.RSVP is really incredibly useful. Previously I thought I was limited to one endpoint/model per route without using setupController. You're correct about `link-to` but I can live with that for my use case.